# ios show Button with animation show one by one here i add link

Tags: ios, animation, button

I have six button on view with two pair of two grid.The problem is how to show button with animation, here I attach example url how to create  this type of animation. 
In this example when you click on menu button then show button in side menu view with animation 
https://github.com/djardon/SideMenuFrostedAnimated
I tried this but I can't get any success.
I have two button one is btnHome and second is btnAbout:

```
-(void)animationStart
{
    [btnHome setAlpha:0.f];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [btnHome setAlpha:0.f];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [btnHome setAlpha:1.f];
            [self animationStart2];
        } completion:nil];
    }];
}
-(void)animationStart2
{
    [btnAbout setAlpha:0.0f];

    //fade in
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{

        [btnAbout setAlpha:1.0f];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        //fade out
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{

            [btnAbout setAlpha:0.0f];

        } completion:nil];

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   btnHome.alpha=0.0;
   btnAbout.alpha=0.0;


}

-(void)animationStart
{

   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:0.0f options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut     animations:^{
       btnHome.alpha=1.0;
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self animationStart2];
   }];

}

-(void)animationStart2
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:0.0f options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut     animations:^{
       btnAbout.alpha=1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}

- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender
{
   [self animationStart];
}
```

Here initially i am setting the buttons alpha value to 0.0f. On click of third button i am showing these two buttons.